# Restrict onEdit trigger to only one sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I would like to use this code :

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.rowStart === 1 && e.range.columnStart === 1) { 
    e.range.offset(0,1).clearContent();
  }
}
```

but only on a tab called '**Inventory**'.
Could you kindly help?

Answer (score 1):

The `IF` statement in your `onEdit(e)` script already tests for row and column. You want to test for sheet name also.

This isn't an uncommon question and yours is close duplicate of [Google Script onedit(e) event restricted to a specific sheet and specific range](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46500020/1330560) with a good answer by @Tanaike.

In your case, extend your `if` statement like this:

`if(e.range.rowStart === 1 && e.range.columnStart === 1 && e.source.getSheetName() === "Inventory") {`